# Excel Function- Circular Reference

Tags: excel, circular-reference

I am trying to split cell culture in my lab and want to create an excel spreadsheet with a formula that will calculate the amount of culture required to be transferred (Cell B2) based on a measure cell density (input into cell A2) in order to receive a particular cell density of the culture. The general formula is:

(X ml Culture)(count VCC) = (Seeding density target)(media + X ml Culture)
Where X ml of Culture is to be cell B2 and calculated for when the lab technician inputs a value for the 'count VCC' (cell A2).

So, essentially I want to write a program that will calculate for cell B2 when a value is input into cell A2, where:

(B2)(A2) = (0.5)(50 + B2)

```
B2= ((0.5)*(50 + B2))/A2
```

However, I keep receiving the circular reference warning. Unfortunately, I have been unable to isolate B2 on one side of my equation as well. Is there a way I can write a program that will subsequently solve for B2 when a value for A2 is input? So if 3.00 was input for A2, it will cause B2 to be calculated as 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the formula to eliminate the circular reference I get

```
B2=25/(A2-0.5)
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. The help is very much appreciated!!

Comment: Can someone point out why this is correct? I'd have thought it was going to be `B2=50/(2*(A2))`

Comment: Rearrange so that you have B2 on one side of the equal sign: B*A=25+B/2, now subtract B/2 to yield B*(A-1/2)=25, and then divide by the A-term.